# Why does 沒收 mean confiscate?

Tags: meaning

When I first heard [沒收](https://www.omgchinese.com/dictionary/chinese/%E6%B2%92%E6%94%B6), I thought 沒收 meant "not receive", as in the [screen cap below](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2gbvsMulV4).

[image]

But then I was startled that [沒收](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/confiscate) means  [confiscate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E6%B2%A1%E6%94%B6) too! Why? Is confiscation  related to "not receive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

沒收(mò shōu) is a two characters word that means "confiscate".

沒收(méi shōu) is a phrase consisting of two words, "not" and "accept". (I didn't accept his money - 我**沒收**他的錢)

沒收到(méi shōu dào) is a phrase consisting of two words, "not" and "receive". (Didn't receive anything after a long wait - 等了佷久都**沒收到**東西)

Comment: But you grok why I am startled? I never knew that 沒收 (mò shōu) and (méi shōu) are HomoGraphs!

Comment: Yes, I understand that confusion. I suggest always paying attention to pronunciation and its specific uses when learning a new Chinese word/character. For example, the word/character "難", is pronounced "nán" as in the word 困難( difficulty); "nàn" as in the word 難民(refugee). There are too many such cases :)

Comment: Thank you so much! So 沒收 (mò shōu) isn't semantically related to (méi shōu)? They don't share any meaning?

Comment: That is another good question to ask about :)

Comment: But I asked it above already.

Comment: The simple answer is no. (méi) simply means "not", while (mò) means "submerge/dive/drown/disappear".

Comment: They aren't the same (obviously), but I think they are related etymologically. Outlier gives "retrieve something out of water" (original meaning) >> "sink" >> "not have". The are clearly different morphemes with different usage in modern Chinees, however, but this type of relationship can still help to make sense of the charcaters involved.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why your question was downvoted. I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: @OlleLinge that user has made what must be the 20th sockpuppet account on Chinese SE alone, and has gotten banned across multiple stack exchange networks repeatedly for poor-quality questions. The questions never show any sign of improvement.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! That makes sense. Looking at just this one instance makes it seem okay, assuming that the poster is new to learning Chinese.

Comment: It's tricky to moderate.  Banning a master sockpuppeteer is somewhat ineffective.  Please be aware that most people seeing these questions/answers are not aware of what's going on behind the scenes.